# Why is #define used after an #undef directive?

Tags: c, preprocessor

I'm reviewing the open source [FANN](https://github.com/libfann/fann) library. As far as I have examined, the developers contributing to the project are quite experienced in C. But I wonder why they do the following in [doublefann.h](https://github.com/libfann/fann/blob/master/src/include/doublefann.h) file:

```c
#undef DOUBLEFANN
#define DOUBLEFANN
```

What's the purpose of removing an identifier using `#undef` and then redefining it using `#define`?

Comment: Either a mistake or its to make sure that *DOUBLEFANN* doesnt have a value

Comment: If you don't remove it first, you'll get an error if the macro is already defined, because redefining a macro is not allowed.

Comment: redefining a macro with the same exact definition is allowed and ignored, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any secret; it's just that the author of that code wanted to override any existing preprocessor-value of `DOUBLEFANN` (e.g. as set by an earlier line in some header-file, or perhaps as provided by a `-DDOUBLEFANN=something` argument on the compiler's command-line) and replace it with his own definition of `DOUBLEFANN` as a defined preprocessor macro with an empty value.

As to *why* the author felt it was necessary to do that, I have no idea.

Comment: The interesting thing is that they don't do this for the other macros.

Comment: @Barmar probably it was a workaround because he was getting warnings.